# javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean under name reportObject

Tags: java, struts

I tried to modify an application written by someone else. This code gives me the error:

```
<TD class="saisie">
   <html:select styleClass="saisie" value="<%= reportParameterForm.getRptTyp() %>" name="reportParameterForm" property="NomRptTyp" size="1" onchange="document.forms[0].submit()">
     <html:options name="reportObject" property="lstRptTyp"  labelName="reportObjet" labelProperty="NomRptTyp" />
   </html:select>
</TD>
```

But this code works:

```
<TD class="saisie">
    <html:select styleClass="saisie" value="<%= reportParameterForm.getReportName() %>" name="reportParameterForm" property="reportName" size="1" onchange="document.forms[0].submit()">
        <html:options name="reportObjet" property="lstCodReport"  labelName="reportObjet" labelProperty="lstNomReport" />
     </html:select>
</TD>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question--it means there's nothing named `reportObject`. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: reportObject exist, the only difference between the working and not working is the property, the working property "lstCodReport" is from the original code and the property lstCodReport I define it myself. Thanks you

Comment: You have a typo in the name `reportObjet`?